# How to let JSF skip getter method call after clicking of button on that page?

Tags: jsf

Actualy I want after clicking logout session get invalidate. But it is going firstly on getter setter and there I created a session. After that is goes to session invalidate method. And it will throw exception.

How would I skip getter setter on click of button and directly call the action method?

Comment: please, elaborate better the question, it's hard to understand if you had tried anything at all and what that was.

Comment: just tell me how would i skip getter setter on click of button.And directly call the actin jsf 2.0 method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't do business job in getters/setters. The getters/setters should solely do the things as their name suggests: returning a property or setting a property. Nothing more. It should not load/preinitialize properties. The loading/preinitializing should be done by a (post)constructor or action(listener) method.

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Comment: Can I call Directly to method for rendered which can give me true and false in return.

Comment: Yes, if you prepare it in (post)constructor of the bean or action(listener) of a previous request, as said. This is less costly if the bean is in view scope. It's hard to give a kickoff code example as long as you don't show the code of your current approach in flavor of an SSCCE.

Comment: can u please elaborate it little bit with example

Comment: General examples are already given in the "See also" link. A specific example suitable for your case cannot be given because your current functional requirement and code approach is not clear, as said. I can for example not imagine a sensible real world use case of creating the session in a getter.